# Wifi installation issues with a Sitecom 300N x2 Wireless Network dongle

Tags: installation, wireless, 10.10

Linux newbie here, anyway so here is the problem, I run Ubuntu 10.10 and I have a Sitecom 300N x2 Wireless Network dongle with chipset 8192SU, I used ndiswrapper to install my Windows Wireless driver because Sitecom doesn't have a linux driver, it says hardware present but it doesn't find any Wireless networks, nor does it connect to one. What can I do?

The command "dmesg | grep ndis" gave this output in the terminal:

```
[    9.999954] ndiswrapper version 1.56 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[   11.111901] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList'
[   11.111973] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists'
[   11.112099] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver'
[   11.112161] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMdl'
[   11.112220] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMDeregisterMiniportDriver'
[   11.112280] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferListPool'
[   11.112339] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool'
[   11.112399] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeMdl'
[   11.112457] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMAllocatePort'
[   11.112515] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMNetPnPEvent'
[   11.112573] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMFreePort'
[   11.112631] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete'
[   11.112780] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSetMiniportAttributes'
[   11.112848] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisOpenConfigurationEx'
[   11.112946] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateStatusEx'
[   11.113017] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMOidRequestComplete'
[   11.113112] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority'
[   11.113200] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateIoWorkItem'
[   11.113271] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeIoWorkItem'
[   11.113342] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisQueueIoWorkItem'
[   11.113413] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferList'
[   11.113481] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBind'
[   11.113547] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBindClass'
[   11.113613] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbindClass'
[   11.113680] ndiswrapper (import:233): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbind'
[   11.113742] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:206): couldn't prepare driver 'net8192su'
[   11.148888] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:108): couldn't load driver net8192su; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[   11.365200] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[   12.818573] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.819183] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.819796] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.820505] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.821115] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.821726] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.822339] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.822948] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.823560] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
[   12.824204] Modules linked in: snd_wavefront snd_emu10k1(+) snd_cs4236 snd_usb_audio snd_wss_lib snd_opl3_lib snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus nouveau(+) snd_pcm i915 snd_usbmidi_lib snd_util_mem snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd_mpu401 snd_mpu401_uart snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper snd_seq ppdev snd_timer snd_seq_device drm ndiswrapper snd parport_pc emu10k1_gp intel_agp ns558 gameport soundcore i2c_algo_bit shpchp lp video output agpgart parport usbhid hid 8139too 8139cp mii floppy
```

Comment: Please run: dmesg | grep ndis and edit your question to add your findings. It will report to us the kernel messages relating to ndiswrapper.

Comment: Okay I posted the output but it's a very long text!

Comment: Yikes! I am not quite sure if it's a Windows driver error or an ndiswrapper (the package) error. Where did you get the Windows .inf and .sys files? Are you aware that ndiswrapper requires Windows XP files. Not Vista, not 7, not 3.1, etc.

Comment: The driver is not specific to a OS, it works for XP, Vista 7 and even MacOSx. I used a common 8192SU.inf

Comment: I don't believe the ndiswrapper mechanism nor your dmesg results agree. Moreover, the 8192SU package I downloaded from Realtek's own site differentiates between Vista and XP and between x86 and x86_64. I suggest you delete the not-functioning .inf and start over with the correct x86 or x86_64 XP .inf and .sys files as appropriate.

Comment: So I need a Realtek one instead of Sitecom?

Comment: Either, but it needs to be XP and x86 or x86_64, as appropriate.

Comment: I did visit Realtek's website and they offer a Linux driver compatible with my current kernel version, is that something worth looking into or should I go ahead and do it via ndiswrapper?

Comment: Installing the native driver is difficult and involves several prereqisites. If you have ndiswrapper installed, you are already 90% done. Later Ubuntu versions have rtl8192cu installed by default. We'll be glad to help in either event.

Comment: I was thinking of just upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 Natty to get rid of this problem, I also have GPU issues that can be easily solved if I have internet on ubuntu, if I remember correctly that command was sudo apt-get nvidia-current and you're done, I think upgrading to 11.04 is way easier, although it might hog my system too much since I don't run that powerful hardware, how much heavier is 11.04 compared to 10.10?

Answer (score 0):

Please erase your current non-performing driver:

```
   sudo ndiswrapper -e 8192SU
```

...or whatever is reported as the driver here:

```
   ndiswrapper -l
```

Then go here and download the Windows RTL8192SU: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=2&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

I believe the file is named RTL8192SU_AutoInstallPackage.zip. Drag and drop it to your desktop. Right-click and select 'Extract Here.' Now do:

```
   arch
```

Do you have a 32-bit system (i686) or a 64-bit system (x86_64)? Now do:

```
   cd Desktop/88_91_92SU_Driver
```

Press Tab and the remainder will fill in automatically. Press Enter. Now do:

```
    sudo ndiswrapper -i WinXP/net8192su.inf
```

If you have a 64-bit system, substitute WinX64 for WinXP above. Now do:

```
    sudo ndiswrapper -m
    sudo modpprobe ndiswrapper
```

It is working now?